# Adding / grouping classes in php

Tags: php, function, class, github

I am integrating a [Github library](https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics/blob/master/README.md)

My main issue is that I have absolutly no idea of how to use or even referencing these classes. Here is what I have done but I get error (listed below) and my php reporting is on

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Class 'DaveChild\TextStatistics\TextStatistics' not found in /Users/Mac3/Documents/Sites/Text-Statistics-master/index.php on line 10
```

**and here is a simple code**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
use \DaveChild\TextStatistics as TS;
$textStatistics = new TS\TextStatistics;
$text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
echo 'Flesch-Kincaid Reading Ease: ' . $textStatistics->fleschKincaidReadingEase($text);
```

and location of my file which is index.php is in main directory. So if I need to include or reference to class I have to link this like

```
src/DaveChild/TextStatistics
```

Many thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to include or require the classfiles

```
require "path/to/Class/class.php";
```

and then instanciate by

```
$textStatistics = new TextStatistics();
```

Comment: Doesn't work Fatal error: Class 'TS\TextStatistics' not found in line 10

Comment: you are right. but i figured out that it must be something with the namespace. i commented out all namespace lines in the class files. this worked for me.

Comment: You were correct, I have added only class and no other files within it, included it in my project and it works like a charm with your solution - I believe the actual class has an error on line 328 but if commented out it works

Answer (score 1):

As you can see this library seems to be compatible with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org). So all you need to do is using composer, and include the vendor autoload file on a bootstrap file, and it should roll out by itself. :)

Comment: True, but I can't install composer on my local machine, Im not allowed to.

Comment: you don't need to install it globally, you can also install it locally for your project. Just grab the phar, and it's ready to use :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. It works now but with other solution.